# Does Spartacus support Hybris on-premise?

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

The project I am working on is a SAP Hybris on-premise eCommerce application. We are planning to migrate our current B2B Accelerator to a Spartacus Storefront. Since ours is not based on SAP Commerce Cloud, wanted to know the compatibility of Spartacus with on-premise version.

Comment: "on premise" is wrong and SAP terminology. It has to be "on premises" (only plural). Or short: "onprem". :-)

Answer (score 5):

I think it would work on local. However, 1905 is recommended, although it also works with 1811 and1808, but with reduced functionality.

See: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what do you mean by it would work on local?

Comment: @AneeshNair By "local", I meant if you tried to build it on your local machine.

Answer (score 2):

It will definitely work local. If you follow the project on github you`ll see a good installation instruction which installs Spartacus in the context of En Premise Hybris.

I ask myself the opposite. Will it be possible to attach to a Cloud version? But I would say: Definitely yes, because actually you just need the *webservices-Extensions to be active....

Answer (score 1):

Spartacus currently supports onpremise and cloud editions of Hybris.
As mentioned above, 1905 is recommended as there were changes to backend APIs to add new functionality. For example, SmartEdit only works with 1905, as does password reset. Guest Checkout is to be added soon after 1.0 but will also require 1905.

However as we move forward in time, there might be features in Spartacus that only work in cloud. For example, there is a new cloud cart coming that only is available through SAP Commerce Cloud (not onprem). In this case, we would add the feature to Spartacus, and it would only work with cloud edition. It doesn't mean Spartacus stops working with onprem cart, just that the new feature we added only works with cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spartacus works with On-Primise but full features are enabled in 1905. But soon they may release some SAP cloud only feature. Spartacus release information can be checked on [Spartacus Documentation Website](https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/release-information/)

Answer (score 0):

Libraries that are “released” are new, official, tested Spartacus libraries available to the public (hosted on npmjs.com)
We usually release new libraries every 2 weeks
A change in minor means we added new features, but they are configured to be off by default, so as not to cause compatibility issues. A new minor also means inclusion of changes or bug fixes that may affect compatibility, but these are also controlled by feature flags. So all significant changes are “opt-in”. See feature flag documentation for more information.